# ¿Como realizo una consulta linq que ordene en grupo mi resultado?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Lo que quiero hacer es un group by en mi consulta de linq pero no se realmente cual sea la sintaxis correcta para que msalga de forma correcta:

Código Actual:

```
public List<Section> getSectionsClass()
{
    var context = GetDbContext();
    return (from cs in context.contenido_seccion
            join c in context.clase on cs.materiaId equals c.materiaId
            group cs by cs.id into gr
            select new Section()
            {
                Name = cs.nombre,
                Id = cs.id,
                IdClass = c.id
            }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Me sale un error después del `gr` en el `select` y el error dice de la siguiente forma:

```
Ambiguos invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas creo que el problema es que intentas acceder a alguna tabla que no esta en el ambito debido al orden de la consulta. Prueba con esto:

```
    public List<Section> getSectionsClass()
{
    var context = GetDbContext();
    return (from cs in context.contenido_seccion
            group cs by cs.id into gr
            join c in context.clase on gr.materiaId equals c.materiaId

            select new Section()
            {
                Name = gr.nombre,
                Id = gr.id,
                IdClass = c.id
            }
    ).ToList();
}
```